# Join performance on STRING vs on DECIMAL (Impala)

Tags: sql, impala, hue

In my database I have attributes consisting only from digits. What would give you a better performance when joining on those fields - if they were of a type of STRING or DECIMAL? Intuitively I would say DECIMAL but maybe someone has got more concrete knowledge/experience on how it looks on impala?

Comment: Not about performance, but do some of your attributes start with 0? Then you can't use numeric types anyway :) General rule - non-numeric data, like phone numbers or PIN or SSN or EAN and other number-like identifiers must be stored as text.

Comment: That is a good point, thanks.

Comment: It heavily depends on requirements i think. Sometime you cant avoid having string or date. Now, from performance perspective, i think sequence can be int, bigint, decimal, float, double and then comes string. But you need to be extremely careful while using decimal, float, or double in join, impala sometime add extra digits in the end of decimal - like 123.45796373738. also, this will not give you a lot of perf benefits for sure because memory needed while joining string/int are similar/almost same.